# How to plot a Plotly graph with hexadecimal value in the Y axis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, plotly

I have a data frame as shown below.I need to plot this using plotly.My Y axis value is hexadecimal.

```
Device_ID   OTP_TRIM_BIT
    
    TTK_536     0x01
    TTK_537     0x01
    TTK_538     0x01
    TTK_542     0x01
    TTK_543     0x01
    FFK_571     0x0e
    FFK_572     0x0e
    FFK_573     0x0e
    FFK_574     0x0e
    FFK_575     0x0e
    SSK_586     0x02
    SSK_587     0x02
    SSK_588     0x01
    SSK_589     0x01
    SSK_590     0x02
    FSK_601     0x01
    FSK-602     0x01
    FSK_603     x01
    FSK_604     0x01
    FSK_605     0x01
    SFK_616     0x00
    SFK_617     0x00
    SFK_618     0x00
    SFK_619     0x0f
```

May  I know how to approach this.I need device id in X axis and trim bit in Y axis

Comment: `int(hexstring, 16)` is your friend here: `df.OTP_TRIM_BIT.apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))`

Comment: I am new to this.if you don't mind could you please share the complete code

Comment: Is the problem that you can't plot beucase it is hex or is your question about how to plot said data displaying the values still in hex, but scaled according to their numeric value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the hex strings using [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) with base `16`:

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.bar(x=df.Device_ID, y=df.OTP_TRIM_BIT.apply(lambda x: int(x, 16)))
fig.write_html('first_figure.html', auto_open=True)
```

[image]

or using the pandas plotly plotting backend:

```
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"
fig = df.assign(OTP_TRIM_BIT=df.OTP_TRIM_BIT.apply(lambda x: int(x, 16))).plot.bar(x='Device_ID', y='OTP_TRIM_BIT')
fig.show()
```

(if the trim bit entry of device ID FSK_603 is indeed `x01` instead of `0x01` you can use for instance `.apply(lambda x: int(x if x[0]=='0' else '0' + x, 16)))` instead)

Comment: Thank you it's working.May I know is there any way to convert hex to string and plot the same.

Comment: The trim bit column is of type string, you can plot it directly as categories (`df.plot.bar(x='Device_ID', y='OTP_TRIM_BIT')`) but the values on the y-axis appear in the order of appearance in the dataframe, they are not sorted numerically. This is probably not what you want.